# Как сделать прилепание правого блока к низу страницы при прокрутке?

Tags: css

У меня такая структура шаблона:
[image: Картинка]

Как можно сделать, чтобы Блок 1 и Блок 2 прилепали к низу страницы, когда прокручиваешь? Дело в том, что область с контентом всегда длинная, и чтобы справа не было пустоты, хотелось, чтобы там были блоки.
В группах Вконтакте так сделано. Сколько бы не пролистывал страницу вниз, правый блок прилепает к нижней границе экрана.

Если можно, подскажите вариант без скриптов (или с лёгкими скриптами). Пробовал добавить к Блоку 2 position sticky, но это не помогает.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Обернуть их в общий контейнер и прописать ему

```
position: sticky;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: Почему-то это не работает. Обернул блоки в div, прописываю ваш код, и ничего.